# configure a subdomain in apache version 2.4.*

Tags: linux, apache, virtualhost

I have the following configuration for subdomain in my httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin foo@bar.com
    DocumentRoot "/home/www"
    ServerName bh.dev
    ServerAlias *.bh.dev
    ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/bh-error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/bh-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/srv/www/htdocs"
    ServerName blog.bh.dev
    ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/bh-error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/bh-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

The **bh.dev** and **bh.dev/blog** URLs are successfully displayed, but **blog.bh.dev** is not. What is the problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`blog.bh.dev` request is handled by the first definition itself as it also qualifies to be under `bh.dev`. So placing the second virtual host definition above the first one would solve the problem.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/srv/www/htdocs"
    ServerName blog.bh.dev
    ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/bh-error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/bh-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin foo@bar.com
    DocumentRoot "/home/www"
    ServerName bh.dev
    ServerAlias *.bh.dev
    ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/bh-error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/bh-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

As a general rule, I always place more specific definitions above the more generic ones.

Comment: I've replaced definitions of the virtual hosts as you suggested, but unfortunately the problem wasn't resolved.

Comment: you need to restart apache after this though

Comment: Of course I restarted apache every time when I am editing the configuration file.